# Indexing MySQL JSON columns in TypeORM

Tags: mysql, typeorm

Is it possible to index MySQL JSON column in TypeORM?

```js
export const languages = [ 'en', 'de', 'fr', 'es', 'it', 'ru', 'jp', 'cn' ] as const;
export type Language = typeof languages[number];

  @Entity('profiles')
  export class Teacher {
    @IsIn(languages, { each: true })
    @Column('json')
    languages?: Language[];
  }
```

Performance-wise would adding Languages entity and OneToMany relationship be a better option than working indexing JSON column? This is important to me as I would have several such columns by which I would need to filter data.

If this is not possible with MySQL would it be possible with PostreSQL?

Comment: In general, using normal forms for tables is going to be more efficient and more correct. The more questions I see about MySQL and JSON, the more I conclude that JSON is the worst thing to happen to relational databases. But it depends on the queries you need to run. There are always exception cases where denormalization is worthwhile, even though it introduces risks.

Comment: But to answer your question, I think what you are looking for is [multi-valued indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued), which is a new feature in MySQL 8.0.17.

Comment: @BillKarwin where do you see use for JSON columns? Would JSON make sense for storing data like a list of links with some metadata if there is no need to use it for filtering/sorting?

Comment: Yeah, I often write that you should reference JSON columns _only_ in the select-list of a query. So you can extract semi-structured data, but if you need to search or sort, store the data needed for those in normal columns. Storing data you need for relation operations in JSON leads you down the path of the [Inner-Platform Effect antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect).